# How to cover all branches of function with #available statement with XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I have a function with an #available statement and would like to cover all branches with a unit test using XCTest. Is that possible?

```
func foo() -> String {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        // Compute something using new iOS 13 API
    } else {
        // Compute it the old way
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the other target simulator with the required OS installed when you run your tests

Comment: That would then only cover the other branch and therefore not give me the desired 100% code coverage. Also in a CI pipeline I can't be sure there's a simulator with a lower iOS version installed.

Comment: You can run tests as many times on targets you want to. Check `man xcodebuild`. To prepare simulators use `xcrun simctl`.